# Passing values between classes for tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get my application to take the string that the user chooses from a listbox and use it in other parts of my code. Initially I am just trying to print the value once the user exits the app. My code looks like the following:

```
class Arrivals(tk.Frame):

    def showSelected(self):
        self.item = self.listbox.get(listbox.curselection())


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="arrivals", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        listbox = tk.Listbox(self, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
        listbox.config(width=0)
        counter = 0
        

        for i in listan_2:
            listbox.insert(counter, i[2] + ' ' + i[0] + ' ' + i[1])

        listbox.pack()


        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text='Choose arrival',
                            command=lambda: [self.showSelected, controller.show_frame(registrering)]).pack(pady=20)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to home", command=lambda:[controller.show_frame(StartPage),
                                                                        showSelected()])
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()
```

at the very end of my code, I am trying to print out the value using

```
arrivals.item
```

and I end up with the following error message:

```
AttributeError: type object 'arrivals' has no attribute 'item'
```

To recap, I want the string 'item' to be accessible to other classes.
I have searched for an answer but none presented have been able to solve this. I do not want to use global variables.

Comment: initiate the class first e.g. `arrivals = Arrivals()` and then `arrivals.item`, also always define `__init__` first and use `snake_case` for functions, methods and variables and `CapitalCase` for class names

Comment: this `i[2] + ' ' + i[0] + ' ' + i[1]` can be reduced to `f'{i[2]} {i[0]} {i[1]}'`

Comment: in the `lambda` (`self.button`) should be `self.showSelected()` not `self.showSelected`. Also avoid using lists inside `lambda`s. It's easier to debug (and see your mistakes) if you just define a normal python function.

Comment: @Matiiss Thanks for your suggestions. I have reduced as suggested. Also thanks for sharing how to properly name functions and classes. Greatly appreciated! I did try your suggestions regarding my question. However I receive the following error message: 
```
    arrivals = Arrivals()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'controller'
```

Comment: Then show how you are instantiating the class.

Comment: @CoolCloud

`arrivals = Arrivals()`
and then `arrivals.item`

Comment: Where is `arrivals.item` called? You probably have to put that inside a function. Also the error says, you are not passing in `parent`, and `controller`, thats defined at `__init__(self, parent, controller)` here.

Comment: @CoolCloud
I have tried to call it at the very end of the code, after ` app.mainloop() `. I have also tried to called it inside a different class but receive the same error message. 

Do I need to pass self, paret and controller when I call the function?

Comment: I would recommend you attend a tutorial on OOP, you need to have `root`, and a controller to pass onto the class or it will throw error each time.

Comment: inside `__init__` you could use `self.item = None` or `self.item = ""` to create it at start with some default value.

Comment: you forgot `()` in `lambda: [self.showSelected(), ...` - so it never execute it when you press button `'Choose arrival'`. Maybe better create normal function with `self.showSelected(), controller.show(...)` instead of strange `lambda: [...]` - it will be more readable.